# Snapping lines together in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, snapping, road

I'm using QGIS 3.8.2. I have a set of lines which represent a road network. However as I have taken different layers from different data sources the lines which represent the same road don't overlap. An example is given below:

[image: Lines representing the same network don't overlap]

This issue has turned out to be problematic for the analysis that I am supposed to do. Is there any way in which I can solve this problem so that lines representing the same road overlap.

Answer (score 1):

If your lines are in different layers, you can use the algorithm "Snap geometries to layer". Select the reference layer and the layer you want to snap to it, and specify a tolerance of snapping.